# How to use "Next/Previous" suggestion shortcuts for Github Copilot on a Mac?

Tags: pycharm, github-copilot

I am trying to use GitHub Copilot on my Mac with Pycharm. Tab works great but I can't cycle through the previous and next code suggestion. Documentation says I should use:

```
Option+]
 
Option+[
```

but if I do, I only get brackets in my code. I should just press Option + 5 or Option + 6 right?

Comment: same problem. . . no one is talking about this :*

Answer (score 27):

I thought I had this problem.

It turned out that the current version of copilot simply only had one suggestion in a lot of cases.

You can see if copilot has alternate suggestions by hovering your mouse over the suggestion. For me, in the cases where the keyboard shortcuts 'didn't work', there simply were no other suggestions available.

Comment: does hovering indicate something? can't see it

Comment: @matanster yes, a tooltip appears with the number of available suggestions https://i.imgur.com/32DpOX9.png

Comment: Thanks that was it. Though in JetBrains IDEs (checked GoLand 2023.3.4), there's no tooltip on hover. But if you press the `Option+]` keystroke multiple times, a small tooltip show up saying `No more Copilot suggestions available`.

Comment: The UI can be misleading sometimes. I have observed a single sugggetion, but you can press Ctrl+Enter to get a full list.

Answer (score 10):

For Visual Studio Code

```
Manage -> Keyboard Shortcuts
```

search for these two expressions;
Previous

```
editor.action.inlineSuggest.showPrevious
```

Next

```
editor.action.inlineSuggest.showNext
```

Decide which shortcuts you want to put.

Congrats it's working now.

Answer (score 8):

You should just update the shortcut.

In pycharm, webstorm.... : go to "Preference" > "Keymap" and look for "Copilot: show previous /next completion" and add your custom keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in VScode. You can use

> Option+\

to trigger the first suggestion then use next and prev shortcuts to cycle through the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Alt+]` and `Alt+[` on GNU/Linux. For other Keyboard shortcuts, for all other Operating Systems and IDEs/Editors, refer to the link: https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/configuring-github-copilot/configuring-github-copilot-in-your-environment?tool=vscode

Answer (score 0):

I got configured NvChad and neovim on my mac, both works amazing. I you didn't modify the default Copilot key map `TAB` then you should be fine following the recommendations for the Copilot plugin.

I use `OPT` + `[` or `OPT` + `]` for the suggestion, or `TAB` for current suggestion.

`: help Copilot`

```
The argument to copilot#Accept() is the fallback for when no suggestion is
displayed.  In this example, a regular carriage return is used.  If no
fallback is desired, use an argument of "" (an empty string).

Other Maps  

                                                *copilot-i_CTRL-]*
<C-]>                   Dismiss the current suggestion.
<Plug>(copilot-dismiss)

                                                *copilot-i_ALT-]*
<M-]>                   Cycle to the next suggestion, if one is available.
<Plug>(copilot-next)

                                                *copilot-i_ALT-[*
<M-[>                   Cycle to the previous suggestion.
<Plug>(copilot-previous)

                                                *copilot-i_ALT-\*
<M-\>                   Explicitly request a suggestion, even if Copilot
<Plug>(copilot-suggest) is disabled.
```